# Is this how you properly add a new item to the state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to add the oldWorkout object to the store so i can use what i push into it, but whatever I try, it doesn't add to the store, even if I start with the oldWorkout object directly in the state and just push the data into it there.

```
const initialState = {
    workoutlist: [],
}

const workoutList = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'LOAD_DATA':
            let oldWorkout = {};
            state.workoutlist.map((workout) => {
                if(workout.id === action.id){
                     return oldWorkout = Object.assign(workout);
                }
                return workout;
            });
            return state ={
                ...state,
                oldWorkout
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default workoutList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const initialState = {
 workoutlist: [],
 oldWorkout: {}
}

const workoutList = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {

 case 'LOAD_DATA':
  return {
    ...state,
    workoutlist: state.workoutlist.map((workout) => {
      if (workout.id === action.id) {
        state.oldWorkout = Object.assign(workout);
      }
    return workout
    })
  };
default:
  return state;
 }
}

 export default workoutList
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

This is the most proper way of changing redux/component/class state

```
const initialState = {
    workoutlist: [],
    oldWorkout: null // add new property to state, use false or null
}

const workoutList = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'LOAD_DATA':
            const item = state.workoutlist.find(v => v.id === action.id) // just find item
            if (item) {
                return {
                    ...state, // copy old state to new state
                    oldWorkout: item // change oldWorkout
                }
            }
            return state

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default workoutList;
```